# Python .strip() returning incorrect value?

Tags: python, string, strip

I encountered a weird behaviour with the build-in .strip() method for python strings and would like to know if this is a bug or if I'm simply using it the wrong way. From my understanding, the method crops the string which is given as an argument. I would expect that

```
'bla.raw'.strip('.raw')
```

would return 'bla' but instead I get 'bl' without the 'a'. I'm running Python 3.7.

Cheers

Comment: `strip` doesn't do what you think it does. It removes all individual characters that you pass to it, so ., r, a, w. If you want to remove `.raw`, use `str.replace(".raw", "")`.

Comment: Alernatively, you could use `split` if you just  want `bla` as output. `'bla.raw'.split('.')[0]`

Comment: `'bla.raw'.strip('raw').strip('.')` does the job as well. So many ways...